# Python Pandas: Find percentage by dividing 2 arrays

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame and I pull 2 pieces of data out (police killings by state, and police killings of blacks by state):

```
import pandas as pd

police_df = pd.read_csv("police.csv")
print(police_df['state'].value_counts())
print((police_df.loc[police_df['race'] == 'B'])['state'].value_counts())
```

I want to know what percentage of the murders in each state are black.  I assume I would do this by dividing the 2 arrays by each other element wise.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sample dataframe `police_df`

```
police_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        state='s1 s1 s1 s1 s2 s2 s2 s2 s3 s3 s3'.split(),
        race=list('BOBOOOOBBBB')
    ))

print(police_df)

   race state
0     B    s1
1     O    s1
2     B    s1
3     O    s1
4     O    s2
5     O    s2
6     O    s2
7     B    s2
8     B    s3
9     B    s3
10    B    s3
```

Use `groupby` and `value_counts` with `normalize=True`

```
police_df.groupby('state').race.value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(fill_value=0)

race      B     O
state            
s1     0.50  0.50
s2     0.25  0.75
s3     1.00  0.00
```